# Python on Mac woes

Tags: python, macos

I want to use the latest Python, 3.6. Installed that, fine.

Now I want to install Beautiful Soup to try some web scraping. After several web searches I found how to operate easy_install. But not on 3.6.

How do I tell the system that everything I want to do is to refer to 3.6?

Comment: How did you install Python?

Answer (score 0):

If you install things system-wide you'd need to use the binaries that come with it, for example pip or python binary that is installed together not the default version. It all depends on your system path which one is picked up but it can get complicated with multiple versions.

I'd advise you install pyenv and use that to change python versions. [It's on brew](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#homebrew-on-mac-os-x). You'll be able to install different versions easily using `pyenv install 3.6.1` and change to different versions using `pyenv shell 3.6.1` for example. Shim executables will know which versions of binaries to use. Just remember to run `pyenv rehash` when you install a new binary so it is registered by peynv.